# Math operators not registering as input?

Tags: c++, string

I'm currently writing my first RPN calculator in C++, and I've encountered a serious dilemma. When the program encounters a mathematical operator as input from the user, it can't seem to understand what it's looking at, and takes it as something that could be converted into a number; I know that this is the largest part of the issue because the runtime error I'm getting tells me that the string in question can't be converted to a decimal via stod.

I've tried using `isdigit()` on the first character in the string (i.e. the only one, `string.at(0)`) to no avail; it still returns true and the computer tries to turn the string into a decimal, causing a crash.
I'll post the function where calculation is taking place, the method I'm using to truncate the user's input into a vector of strings, and the method I'm using to check if the string in question can be converted to a double using stod below:

CALCULATION:

```
double calculate(string inputTemp)
{
    double result;

    //Truncate input into a digestible format via the truncation method
    vector<string> input = truncate(inputTemp);
    int inputTokens = input.size();
    stack<double> stk;
    double num1;
    double num2;
    int i = 0;

    while(inputTokens > 1)
    {
        if(isNum(input[i]))
        {
            cout << input[i] << " pushed to stack" << endl;
            stk.push(stod(input[i]));
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(input[i].at(0))
            {
                case '+':
                    num2 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    num1 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    stk.push(num1 + num2);
                    inputTokens--;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    num2 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    num1 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    stk.push(num1 - num2);
                    inputTokens--;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case '*': case 'x': case 'X':
                    num2 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    num1 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    stk.push(num1 * num2);
                    inputTokens--;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    num2 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    num1 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    stk.push(num1 / num2);
                    inputTokens--;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case '^':
                    num2 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    num1 = stk.top();
                    stk.pop();
                    stk.push(pow(num1, num2));
                    inputTokens--;
                    i++;
                    break;
                default: 
                    cout << "ERROR: invalid operator entered" << endl;
                    i++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    result = stk.top();
    return result;
}
```

TRUNCATING STRINGS:

```
vector<string> truncate(string input)
{
    vector<string> output(input.length());

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = input.at(i);

        switch(c)
        {
            case ' ': j++; break;
            default: output[j] += c; break;
        }
    }

    while(output.back() == "")
    {
        output.pop_back();
    }

    return output;
}
```

CHECK IF NUMBER (Wrote this instead of using `isdigit` so that users could enter decimals and users couldn't enter something like 3AJ)

```
bool isNum(string input)
{
    int numDecimals = 0;
    int nonNumChars = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = input.at(i);

        if(!isdigit(c))
        {
            switch(c)
            {
                case '.': numDecimals++; break;
                default: nonNumChars++; break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(numDecimals < 2 && nonNumChars == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I apologize for the lengthiness of this post, just wanted to give as much info up front as possible. I'm stumped. Please refrain from posting actual code in place of regular advice and pointing out what I'm doing wrong if you can help it, I like to avoid copying other peoples' code when possible. There's less fun and learning stretch if you copy.

Comment: Show a sample of the input that causes the crash, please.

Comment: @Roddy
This is the error it gives me when I enter "2 4 +":
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod

Comment: It should also be noted that I've made it so that it tells me when something has been pushed to the stack and what has been pushed to the stack, and it does that just fine with the numbers, but as soon as it hits the operator, it tells me that "" has been pushed to the stack and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not exactly in the string you're passing to `stod`, but in the array indexing. Look carefully at where you do (and don't) decrement `inputTokens`.

Comment: Huh, never would have guessed that was the root of my issue. I've got it working now.
Now to repeatedly break and fix it again in the process of preparing it for invalid responses, lol.
Thanks a bunch for the help.